# NewRelic multiple metrics display in a chart

Tags: newrelic

It's possible to display several metrics in the same chart using asterisk:

- `Apdex/*` (all)
- `Apdex/cases/*` (all Apdex cases)
- `Apdex/cases/case_study` (a specific one)

However we're limited with the single category `Apdex`.

Is there a way to display in the same chart multiple metrics from different categories?

For example I would like to have those two metrics in the same chart displayed:

- `CPU/User/Utilization/` (exact metric match)
- `GC/ConcurrentMarkSweep` (exact metric match)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible to display data from different scopes in custom dashboards. You can submit a feature request for this additional functionality for custom dashboards here: https://support.newrelic.com. And there are always new features just around the corner so keep an eye out for new possibilities; the best answer could change.

In the meantime you could create a plugin to report the data to New Relic. With a plugin you could have the data that you want to display scoped to the same space allowing you to create a dashboard that shows you the data that you want to see. For more information on this please see https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev

Comment: Thx Steven, we do use custom metrics in our project so I consider grouping metrics I'm interested with under the same category. However usually it's a long story to get code updates on production.